# I have deleted app_data folder accidentally

Tags: asp.net, appdata, app-data

I have deleted an app_data folder accidentally from my project in Visual Studio 2015. It was generated automatically and the database files was there in it. Now I want that folder back,so can you help me how to get that back in my project.

Comment: check you recycle bin it will be there you can click on restore that that will show you in filedirectory than you have to copy code and add manually to your project

Comment: if you used code first &  EF seed data function, you can rebuild this (since you say db was automatically generated) - also you could use version control in future, as delete is permanent (and VS does put that warning up when you are deleting)

Comment: It is not there in Recycle Bin also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaning on a more positive side, so I assume you've only removed the folder from the vs project solution explorer.

You could add it back by clicking on the *show all file* button [Show all file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNgOX.jpg)

and include back the app_data folder.

Comment: But there is no 'show all file' button in my Solution Explorer. My project is not a Console Application. It is a website.

Comment: Hi, try right click your website ->  Add -> Add Asp.Net folder -> select App_data

and check if you can see your database files.